# Auto start chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to make a chrome extension that redirects to a other page when it's loaded. For example, if it's google.nl, go to google.nl?example I managed to get that working, but only when i press the extension button.  I want to run the script from the background.js but i get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

Why do i wan't to reload? Well i don't. it's just to test. The original plan is reading the URL and put the open graph data in my extension.

manifest (part)

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": [
  "<all_urls>"
],
"js": ["background.js"]
}],
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"activeTab",
 "webRequest"
],
"background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(a) {
if (a.url.indexOf("http://www.google.com/") >= 0) {
    reloadExtensions();
    chrome.tabs.get(a.tabId, function(b) {
        if ((b.selected == false)) {
            chrome.tabs.remove(a.tabId)
        }
    });
    return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("close.html")}
}
return {cancel: false}
```

}, {urls: ["http://reload.extensions/"],types: ["main_frame"]}, ["blocking"]);

Answer (score 0):

iirc [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) say you need to put all the URL's you want to redirect in the `permissions` array.

If you don't you will see the following error
[image]

Checkout Catblock example https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest by removing

I don't think you need the content script parts at all, in fact I suspect that is where you are seeing the error.